# OneSignal sendTag right after init doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I am using OneSignal in a Ionic project. I am initializing OneSignal when device is ready:

```
  window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 6, visualLevel: 4});
  window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit(appId)
  // Controls how OneSignal notifications will be shown when one is received while your app is in focus
  .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None) // None means silent
  .endInit();

  // set OS tag to uid in case multiple users on same device
  window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("uid", user.auth.uid);

  });
```

As you can see, right after init I need to send a tag.

My problem is that when I launch the app for the first time, the init it done properly but the sendTag seems not to be done... (on second launch the sendTag is done though).

But I need the sendTag to be done the first time around...

I figured that may be the init is not done yet (or something like that) and that it prevents the sendTag to happen...

Do you know if that's the real problem here ? And would you have any suggestion ? May be a way to know when init is finished (catch a OneSignal event)...

** UPDATE ****

It looks like sendTag if working after all (I simplified my code for the purpose of this post). But the real initial issue I had was when sendTag is called in the getTags' callback.

The following code doesn't executes when written right after endInit():

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getTags(function(tags) {
   if (!tags) window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("uid", user.auth.uid);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue... did you find any solution? thanks

Comment: Nope, I don't use it anymore